# How to invoke document.body.onload event on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension and I wrote all of my code inside `document.body.onload`, but it doesn't work well every time the user visits any website: sometimes it works and sometimes not.

So, I want to invoke the `document.body.onload()` event on my website so that the extension will work correctly everytime the user visits my website, but I need a code to be added to the website not the extension.

Comment: did you tried `window.onload`? it is same as that of `<body onload="">`.

Comment: You can use `$(document).ready` too...

Comment: no the extension already has launched and it has users installed it, so i won't change it code i want to write a code on my website to make it work on

Comment: It's really easy to update your extension. Just publish a new one and it's automatically rolled out to your existing users.

Comment: unfortunately it is installed  from exe not from chrome store